# Где можно посмотреть доступные xml-атрибуты кастомного View-элемента?

Tags: java, android

Вопрос в том, что я добавил в свой проект кастомный `View` элемент

```
<org.adw.library.widgets.discreteseekbar.DiscreteSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/dsbHeight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            app:dsb_indicatorColor="@color/color_white"
            app:dsb_indicatorFormatter="%03d Cm"
            app:dsb_indicatorTextAppearance="@style/CustomFloaterTextAppearance"
            app:dsb_max="220"
            app:dsb_min="145"
            app:dsb_progressColor="@color/ntz_color_lilac"
            app:dsb_rippleColor="@color/ntz_color_yellow"
            app:dsb_scrubberHeight="10dp"
            app:dsb_thumbSize="25dp"
            app:dsb_trackColor="@color/ntz_color_blue"
            app:dsb_trackHeight="10dip"
            app:dsb_value="155" />
```

и для того, чтоб я мог обращаться к функциям которые начитаются с `app` как показано выше я добавил такую строчку в шапку `XML` файла

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

И вот как я это понимаю, есть библиотека с различными функциями, путь к которой мы указали, после чего можем использовать ее возможности. Вопрос в том где можно посмотреть файл со всеми возможными ее функциями? Я так понимаю, что он находиться по этому пути `//schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`, но у меня нет в проекте папки `res-auto`... В общем запутался

Comment: Раньше, надо было использовать конструкцию, вида : `xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.my.package.name"`, потом всё дополнили и появился автогенератор локального `namespace` и все начали писать  `xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: счелкните левой кнопкой, зажав ctrl, по DiscreteSeekBar

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Когда я так делаю, то у меня открывается java класс

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko я просто подумал, что Вам это и надо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строка `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` значит, что в разметке необходимо использовать пространство имен атрибутов с тегом `app` (может быть произвольным именем), которые необходимо получить исходя из имеющихся в разметке классов.

То, какие именно будут доступны атрибуты, определяется кодом самого кастомного класса элемента и посмотреть их можно, посмотрев код класса, либо значения, задекларированные в файле `res/values/attrs.xml` для этого класса.

например:

```
<declare-styleable name="SomeCustomView">
  <attr name="some_custom_attribute" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Здесь для кастомного класса `SomeCustomView` задекларирован собственный атрибут `some_custom_attribute`, присвоить значение в разметке которому можно следующим образом (при условии объявленного пространства имен выше):

```
 app:some_custom_attribute ="someValue"
```

Нет никакого универсального списка этих кастомных атрибутов - их имена, количество и наличие определяется исключительно кодом самого конкретного кастомного класса и связанных с ним задекларированных имен атрибутов в файле attrs.xml.

В IDE данные атрибуты должны быть доступны в автодополнении кода, то есть , набрав `app:` и вызвав автодополнение вы должны получить все доступные в этом пространстве имен атрибуты для подстановки. Так же они должны присутствовать в списке панели атрибутов в визуальном редакторе.

Comment: А кстати какие клавиши вызывают автодополнение?

Comment: в Android Studio оно как бы автоматически срабатывает по мере ввода, а горячие клавиши CTRL + Space (пробел). В Eclipse не в курсе.

Comment: У меня, кстати, не всегда в таких случаях автодополнение что автоматическоу, что на `Ctrl+Space` срабатывает, что, порою, сильно смущает(